# Limit packets per second

Tags: linux

I am using kvm with bridge networking and I want to limit packets per second for all virtual machines.

I know how to do that with iptables, but it's not working. All iptables rules don't apply to the routed vm ips, although `net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 1`.

Comment: Show us some of the iptables rules you've tried.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault -- In order to make this question meet our quality standards it needs some substantial improvement. Please check out [this meta post](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault) and edit your question to include additional information on *what you've tried*, *what you expected*, and *what results you got*.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the kernel to pass packets passing through the bridge to netfilter/iptables:

```
/proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables => pass (1) or don't pass (0) bridged IPv4 traffic to iptables' chains.
/proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-ip6tables => pass (1) or don't pass (0) bridged IPv6 traffic to ip6tables' chains.
/proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-filter-vlan-tagged => pass (1) or don't pass (0) bridged vlan-tagged ARP/IP traffic to arptables/iptables.
```

So to filter IPv4 traffic, you need to set:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables
```

If you're using VLAN's, you'll probably need to enable the `filter-vlan-tagged` option too.

Comment: bridge-nf-call-iptables is already seted to 1
and the same problem all iptables rules doesn't apply to the routed ips 
for example
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -o vmbr0 -s 5.9.154.x -m limit --limit 200/sec -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD 2 -o vmbr0 -s 5.9.154.x -j DROP

this should limit 200 packets per seconde for the routed ip 5.9.154.x but its not work

thank you

Comment: for example if you are trying to block an external ip using iptables it will be blocked from the main server ip but routed ips will be still connectable
i don't use vlans
thanks

Comment: This is all relevant information that you need to include in your original question.